# How to send to a client individually using socket_id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

In client :

```
socket.on("event_test", function(msg){      console.log(msg); 
    alert(msg);
});

function test()
{
    socket.emit("hello","my_username");
}
```

In server:

```
socket.on("hello", function(new_username){
    socket.to(socket.id).emit("event_test", "pobe" );
    console.log(socket.id); // socket id is being printed correctly 
});
```

I wrote this code only to check .to() fuctionality . 
A normal socket.emit works fine . Only when I am trying to send it to a particular client , it is not emitting and i am not able to receive it in client. 
What am i doing wrong ?
followed this : https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
socket.on("hello", function(id, new_username){
    socket.broadcast.to(id).emit("event_test", "pobe" );
});
```

Looking at your cheatsheet you look correct, I'm no expert but I think you may have been sending your message from the server to itself.

EDIT:

If that's not working try:

```
socket.on("hello", function(new_username){
    socket.emit("event_test", "pobe" );
});
```

Comment: The edited one is working fine . But if I want to send it to some other socket  I should be using to . \n i.e. Lets say i have client1 , client2 and a server . When client1 emits something the server should send a msg to client2 . This is what i am trying to achieve .